# Is there any measuring instrument more accurate than the screw gauge?

Tags: measurements

Screw gauges usually have a least count of **0.001cm**. The digital meters measure it more accurately, using laser having a frequency of about 500Hz to 30kHz. However, it doesn't work for substances such as glass, which have greater wave-absorbing properties than that of [most] other substances. *Is there any device -digital or analog- which measures the length of an object in a better way, and more accurately ?*
Instruments having least count even less than 0.001cm might help, but is there a better physical instrument for this purpose ?

Comment: Interferometric devices can have resolution of well below atomic scale (and a physics interferometer like LIGO is far below the size of a nucleus, if I remember correctly). The material really doesn't matter. What matters is the preparation of the sample. At this kind of resolution surface roughness will most likely dominate the resolution limit of the instrument, anyway.

Comment: LIGO's interferometers are designed to measure a distance 1/10,000th the width of a proton, so that's well below the size of a nucleus

Comment: yes, it would serve the purpose. thanks !

Comment: How much precision is needed? Are you trying to make glass lenses?

Comment: @user253751 Precision lenses are generally being measured using interferometry of some sort. A simple method is to bring the lens in contact with a flat plate and illuminate with a coherent source. The interference fringes are a very precise measure of the quality and shape of the lens surface.